# Use PHP to convert PNG to JPEG

Tags: php

I have a website where users have been uploading a bunch of high quality PNG files. I want to use PHP to convert them to JPEG and re-size them to make them smaller in file size.

How can I do this when they upload the file? What is the process for doing this? Is a new image created or is it edited?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this :

```
function pngTojpg($pngImage, $outputPngFile, $outputJpgFile, $quality) {
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($pngImage);

    //Save the png image
    imagepng($image, $outputPngFile);         

    //Save the jpeg image
    imagejpeg($image, $outputJpgFile, $quality);

    // Free up memory
    imagedestroy($image);
}
```

"quality is optional, and ranges from 0 (worst quality, smaller file) to 100 (best quality, biggest file). The default is the default IJG quality value (about 75)"

The php doc : [imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php), [imagecreatefrompng](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php)

These functions are from the GD library, here the installation instruction : [Php GD](http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php)

Comment: Now can I do this with a TMP file then move the uploaded file to the image directory?

Comment: imagecreatefrompng don't save the png, it "returns an image identifier representing the image obtained from the given filename"

Comment: what is the $outputFile variable?

Comment: And how is the new image saved to the proper directory?

Comment: $outputFile is the path/name of the image you want to save, if you want to know what each parameters is doing check the php doc.

Comment: is $image the original file? And will $outputPngFile be the one I want to move to the image directory?

Comment: Yeah sorry my variable was a bit confusing, check the update, $pngImage is the original image, and yes $outputPngFile is the one you want to move to the image directory

Comment: Okay Thank you Alot JP! One last question lol, how can I test this with files already in my /images directory? I don't want to build a form to test on tmp files.

Answer (score 0):

Use ImageMagick to do all kinds of conversions. You should be able to find examples at this link:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Answer (score 0):

Just try ImageMagick:
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php

I think, that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use simple php code to do that but I use and recomend this library to work with images:

Verot - Class Upload http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm

You can convert images to other format, reduce size, transform and do a lot others stuffs.